# When I use QML my backround image seems black

Tags: qt, qt-creator, meego

I am  using simulator  and  meego device.

When I use the simulator there is no problem but  when I install it in my  N9  device there is a  black  background which is where I use qml. Other pages have no problem.

Does anybody know  why?